# How do I extract decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the early learning phases of `python`. The intent is to extract all numbers, including decimals. My function seems to be separating all integers from each value. I'm trying to extract all numbers, including decimals, and sum them all up while adding 2.0. I've attempted to use the `.split()` function but that gave me more trouble.

```
str1 = input("Enter a string with a colon and a number after it: ")
def findSum(str1): 
    temp = "0"
    Sum = 0
    for ch in str1:
        if (ch.isdigit()):
            temp += ch
        else:
            Sum += float(temp)
            temp = "0"
    return Sum + float(temp)
print("Extracted a number from given string and added 2.0 to it: ", findSum(str1) + 2.0)
```

INPUT: "Test: 3.452"

Desired OUTPUT: "5.452"

Comment: do you have sample input and expected output? Alsothe regex library can be very usefull for this. Otherwise you could work with .isnumeric()

Comment: I've not learned regex functions yet, but have been seeing it references a lot while doing searches. My example input would include something along the lines: "Test: 3.452" and I'm wanting the Output: "5.452"

Comment: Your prompt asks for a string with a colon (`:`), your input doesn't have a colon in it. Your code as written is checking for whitespace (that's what `.split()` splits on by default), which makes even less sense. Is this just supposed to parse a `float`? If so, why would adding `2.0` to the result of parsing produce a number just `1.0` larger than the input? What are your constraints here? Why is just calling `float` on the original number(s) not acceptable? Why is `split` with no arguments okay, but you seem to be avoiding `.split('.')` (which would split integer from decimal components)?

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one float in the string you can indeed use split:

```
s = "Test: 3.452"

def findSum(s):
    return float(s.rsplit(":",1)[-1].strip()) + 2

print(findSum(s))
# 5.452
```